# Travelling to Dublin Via Heathrow and changing Terminals in heathrow from T2 TO T3

Tags: transit, lhr, dublin, common-travel-area

I'm travelling from Dubai to Dublin but i have 3 hours transit in Heathrow in which i will have to change flights from T2 TO T3 . I have Egyptian passport and obviously valid Visa to Ireland . the luggage will transferred to the final desitnation ( Dublin )

The question Do i Need Uk Transit Visa from T2 To T3 ?

Comment: Do you have a **Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’ section)**? See section: [Travel to the Channel Islands, the Isle of Man or Ireland, Visa to pass through the UK in transit: Visitor in Transit visa - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa)

Comment: There is no need to close this, since there  are special rules when travelling within the **Common Travel Area**. Immigration Control will be done, on behalf of Ireland, at the port of entry of the UK.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without knowing ALL the details.

- Covid regulations:
  https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-safer-air-travel-guidance-for-passengers#transiting-through-england
- Visa requirements for transit:
  https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa
- Trasit from Egypt to Ireland:
  https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/egypt/transit/republic_of_ireland This seesm to imply that you need a Visa unless you qualify for an exemption
- Heathrow Connection advisor: https://www.heathrow.com/connecting-flights You should put in ALL your details and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

There are special rules when traveling to a destination within the **Common Travel Area**.

For Ireland, as the destination, you do not need a **Visa to pass through the UK in transit** if you have a **Irish biometric visa** (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’ section).

> [Visa to pass through the UK in transit: Visitor in Transit visa - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa)
> ...
> **Travel to the Channel Islands, the Isle of Man or Ireland**
> You might need to apply for a [visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/short-visit-visas) to travel through the UK to get to the Channel Islands, the Isle of Man or Ireland.
>
> You’ll usually need to apply for a [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) [if you’re staying in the UK for more than 48 hours] unless you’re exempt.
>
> You do not need a UK visitor visa if:
>
> - you have a valid visa for the Channel Islands or the Isle of Man
> - you have a valid Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’ section)
>
> ...

Comment: I'm curious about what Timactic says. It would suck to not be allowed to board if the airline things a UK transit visa IS required.